# Capitalize "god"?

Tags: capitalization

I have found 9 examples where I have used "god" in a story I've written. They're all used in the dialog. I don't know if I should capitalize it, so would like to know what you would do. Would you capitalize "god" in all 9 examples?

1. Oh god.
2. Oh my god.
3. Thank god nothing happened.
4. Watch your goddamn language.
5. I swear to god, if you...
6. Help me, goddammit.
7. God bless him.
8. For the love of god, what is he doing?
9. I hate that goddamn couch.

Comment: To the extent that we're not yet all atheists, Anglophones are mostly in the monotheistic / Abrahamic category when it comes to religion. We don't normally capitalise ***goddamn*** and similar derived forms, but we still capitalise all the other instances in your examples because it's essentially a ***proper noun*** (we might just disagree on ***which specific*** one-and-only god/God we're talking about).

Comment: In English, God is a proper noun, because it is a name. While people might disagree over the nature of God, that's less of an issue than if you lowercase it; if you lowercase it, you could be referring to any number of divinities (Greek gods, Roman gods, Incan gods, etc).

Answer (score 2):

You should capitalise the word "God" when it is being used like the name of the supreme being.

So certainly capitalise "Thank God" and "I swear to God"  even if these expressions are not meant as genuine prayers or oaths. Also "Oh my God", although this is such a casual expression, you will see "Oh my god" very commonly.

Don't capitalise words like "goddammit".

Don't capitalise "god" when it is being used as a common noun:  "Many gods were worshipped in the ancient world".

Comment: Arguably, "Oh my god" shouldn't be capitalised because it's being used as a common noun rather than a name, even if you're using it as a prayer towards a god named God.